# Firedac comand batches with postgreSQL connection

Tags: postgresql, delphi, firedac

According to Firedac documentation https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Command_Batches_(FireDAC)

In order to retrieve a dataset array, the sql command should be written as a Anonymous block structure when PostgreSQL version is above 9.

But, anonymous block in PostgreSQL does not return any result set.

The documentation does not provide a full example.

How can I acomplish this?

Delphi 10.3.3

PostgreSQL 14.

Thank´s

Comment: Just to be clear: What I intend to do is to retrieve a dataset array that can be accessed by NextRecordSet command.